# Accessing child's '$invalid' validation prop within a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a reusable directive that will simply add a class to an element based on the `$invalid` property of one of its children.

I started creating the directive, but am unsure of how to go about accessing the `$invalid` prop:

Simplified Markup:

```html
<form>
    <div class="group" ng-validate="emailAddress">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input type="email" name="emailAddress" ng-model="emailAddress" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the directive:

```js
function ngValidate ()
{
    function linkFunction (scope, element, attributes, controller)
    {
        var el = element[0];
        var targetElName = attributes.ngValidate;
        var $targetEl = angular.element(el.querySelector("[name='" + targetElName + "']"));

        $targetEl.on("blur", blurHandler);

        function blurHandler (event)
        {
            console.log($targetEl.$invalid); // always undefined??

            // what I want to happen (sudo code):

            // if $targetEl is $invalid then add class 'error' to element.
            // if $targetEl is $valid then add class 'success' to element.
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: linkFunction
    };
}
```

I'm a little stuck with this, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Ghan's suggestion of using the class name, I have now created a working directive to encapsulate the logic:

Example markup (changed value to 'surname' to avoid confusion):

```
<form>
    <div class="group" ng-validate="surname">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input type="text" name="surname" ng-model="surname" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The working directive:

```
function ngValidate ()
{
    function linkFunction (scope, element, attributes, controller)
    {
        var el = element[0]; // grab the DOM element from the angular/jQuery element.
        var targetElName = attributes.ngValidate;
        var $targetEl = angular.element(el.querySelector("[name='" + targetElName + "']"));

        $targetEl.on("blur", blurHandler);

        function blurHandler (event)
        {
            if ($targetEl.hasClass("ng-invalid"))
            {
                // add remove success class and error class.
                element.removeClass("form-controlGroup--success").addClass("form-controlGroup--error");
            }
            else if ($targetEl.hasClass("ng-valid"))
            {
                // add remove error class and success class.
                element.removeClass("form-controlGroup--error").addClass("form-controlGroup--success");
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: linkFunction
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form name="myform">
    <div class="group" ng-validate="emailAddress">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input type="email" name="emailAddress" ng-model="emailAddress" ng-class="{ 'bademail' : myform.email.$invalid }" required/>
        </div>
    </div> </form>
```

You can also just specify `.group input[type=email] .ng-invalid { color: red; }` in your CSS (ng-invalid is added automatically as a class).

More about all the FormController properties here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I was originally using ng-class, but I'm trying to encapsulate that behaviour so that I don't need to litter the HTML with conditional logic; I am trying to pass a single 'target' attribute value into a directive to do the same thing, but dynamically. I actually have created a different directive (which works) that dynamically adds the ng-class attribute, but this directive was crashing my Cordova app, so I'm trying a different approach

Comment: Why do you need to add dynamically `ngClass`? You have directive, just add the class to element what you want through `element.addClass()`

Comment: Hey @munkychop, since angular will automatically add .ng-invalid to the element, my suggestion is to just use that class. But, if you need to use 'error' or a different class name instead, you could always check to see if `element.hasClass('ng-invalid')`

Comment: @SergeyRomanov I need to add the class to the element based on the validity of the child element.

Comment: @Ghan thanks, I didn't think of checking for that class, I think that should work for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

1. Angular have built-in email validator. You can check if it is valid with `formName.fieldName.$error.email`. But if you just what to figure out basic validation concept then.
2. You apply your directive to div but I think you have to apply it to input
3. You have to use `ngModel` `$validators` or `$parsers` to ad validation. Because `$invalid` is a property of element only with `ngModel`

```

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input type="email" ng-validate="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" ng-model="emailAddress" required/>
            <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.emailAddress.$error.myemail" >Email is not correct</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```

Now you create validation directive.

```
function ngValidate ()
{
    function linkFunction (scope, element, attributes, controller)
    {
        controller.$parsers.push(function(value){
            if(!value || value.length == 0) return;

            controller.$setValidity('myemail', true);

            switch(scope.ngValidate) {
                case 'emailAddress':
                    if(!value.match(/email regex/g)) {
                        controller.$setValidity('myemail', false);
                    }
                break;
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            'ngValidate': '@'
        },
        link: linkFunction
    };
}
```

With this you can also use `ngMessages`.

In general I would recommend to search google for *Angularjs validation*. You can learn a lot there.

**UPDATE**

If you want just to add class to wrapper based on validation of the field.

```
<div class="group" ng-class="myClass(myForm, 'emailAddress')">
```

Now in controller

```
$scope.myClass = function(form, name) {
    var error = !angular.equals({}, form[name].$error);

    if(form[name].$dirty && !error) {
        return 'has-success'
    }
    if((form[name].$dirty || form.$submitted) && error) {
        return 'has-error'
    }
}
```

This will add class `has-error` if there is at least one error in the field or `has-success` if none.

Comment: Thanks but I already know about the email validation. My question is not specific to email. See my first comment on @Ghan's answer.

Comment: Edited and added a solution